# What causes the user to go to new a page when they submit a form, and can it be done in JavaScript?

Tags: html, ajax, http, forms, http-redirect

You supply the `action` and `method` properties on a form, and then when it's submitted, it completes that HTTP `method` using the url specified in `action`. The end result takes the user to a new page, the page returned by the server in response to a POST (or whatever) to that target URL.

What *causes* this redirect? Is it an intrinsic property of how HTML form elements work, or is it just a redirect header in the HTTP response?

I'm trying to reproduce that effect with an ajax POST, *without* just manually writing a line of JS to do the redirect~ I want it to happen automatically, the same way.

Is submitting a form essentially the same as going to the url `www.myHostDomain.com/mySpecifiedFormAction?myFirstFormField=myFirstFormValue&mySecondFormField=mySecondFormValue` ?

That can't be right, since the browser bar is always a GET request.

Comment: Which redirect are you talking about? ... The difference between a POST and a GET is that the POST can have data both in its URL and in its body, a GET has it in the URL

Comment: @LGSon - I believe OP want's to know why the server can't redirect from an AJAX request

Comment: Generally, the redirect will be handled server-side. What is on the back-end actually handling the submitted data?

Comment: When you submit an HTML form, you are taken to a new page: the browser actually renders the response from the server. What *causes* that to happen automatically? If anything the answer would be in the HTML form spec I suppose.

Comment: A form submission is like an anchor tag with an href. It pretty much performs a document.location to the new location using a get request.

Comment: But if you send a GET it also return a new page? ... So does POST using the action parameter as the URL

Comment: You gotta back that up with a reference though, @scrappedcola .

Comment: In this case I think one could say, to make it simple, a POST is a GET with embedded data

Comment: If you have a look here you'll see how it works/looks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form's `action` attribute serves a role of navigation URL, a.k.a. "[plan to navigate](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#plan-to-navigate)". `target` attribute defines where to load that response returned by the server.

So yes, that is "an intrinsic property of how HTML form elements work".

Algorithm of handling form submission is defined in HTML4 and [HTML5 forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html) specifications.

Submitting the form is essentially an ordinary URL navigation (by `<a href>` elements) but with automatic parameters gathering that go either into final navigation URL as parameters ( `<form method="get">` ) or as request body parameters ( `<form method="post">` )

Comment: Finally, a great answer with references instead of just asinine comments telling me to figure it out myself. Thanks!